# nil cell remove from tableview for display

Tags: ios4

-any one can help me to remove UITableViewCell which is nil Or could not hold Any data

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  // Return the number of rows in the section.
  if (flagTable) {
       return [arrSerSug count];
  }
  else {
      return [appDelegate.arrSearch count];
  }
  return 0;
  }

thanks...

Comment: What;s the problem with this code ?

Comment: it will just display one table at a time its good but remaining blank cell also display in both that i dont want now got it question??

Answer (score 0):

Just set your table property from  **UITableViewStylePlain** to **UITableViewStyleGrouped** using:

```
YourTableView.style=UITableViewStylePlain;
```

or **either from Xib file**.

It won't show you remaining cells.